# Programming Google CardDAV in Python

Tags: python, google-contacts-api, carddav

I want to obtain my Google contacts through the CardDAV protocol using preferably Python (open to other languages).

I've come across the `pycarddav` library, but it only works with SabreDAV/DAVical servers, not Google for example.

How one would go about programming an interface to the Google contacts CardDAV using Python (or other language)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google has just today [announced](http://googledevelopers.blogspot.de/2013/06/making-googles-caldav-and-carddav-apis.html) to make CalDAV and CardDAV available for everyone. Google's [CardDAV Documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/carddav/) (also just released today) is probably a good place to start.